# Выполнение скриптов в WebBrowser

Tags: jquery, webbrowser, delphi, javascript, delphi-7

Добрый день, уважаемые программисты!
При загрузке страницы в теге <head> должны выполнятся 2 скрипта. При загрузке через WebBrowser выскакивает ошибка сценария, в которой упомянуто, о невозможности их выполнения. Прошу подсказать, либо направить как разрешить данную проблему. Вот код страницы:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>ESCRM</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/st/images/favicon.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/st/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/st/css/main.css">
        <script src="/st/javascripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/st/javascripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 300px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;margin-top: 200px;border: 1px #aaaaaa solid;border-radius: 20px;padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">

<form action="/login?url=%2F" method="POST" >

                <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите ваш логин"><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"><br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Войти">

</form>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что надо сделать.
Как я понимаю подавить сообщение, запрос к пользователю?

```
// Устранение проблемы: веб браузер выдаёт сообщение: "An error has occurred in the //script on this page". 
wb.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

Взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786302/getting-an-error-with-a-web-browser-control-in-a-winforms-application)

Можете ещё попробовать [WatiN](http://watin.org/)

Comment: @EgorychMaster я загружаю страницу через webbrowser, выскакивает ошибка сценария: мол не может скрипты выполнить. И страничка прогружается не корректно, ее функционал нарушен. Мне нужно чтобы страница прогружалась и скрипты выполнялись, но понятия не имею как их выполнить(((

Comment: По Delphi помочь вам не смогу. Я использовал C#.

Comment: @EgorychMaster и всё же спасибо, что откликнулись)